# React hooks component reloading

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a typescript react app that has a child component called Accordion that when is clicked it is opened. When is opened it renders a table with some data. This accordion is made depending on a group that can be changed with a selector. My problem is that I want that when I change this group by my Accordion component closes if it's opened. I tried to pass a prop to close the Accordion but nothing occurs and I'm starting to be frustrated. How can I reload this component in order for the state to be closed? That's my code:

This is my Accordion component:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, Fragment, ReactChildren, ReactNode } from "react";
import Chevron from "./Chevron"

interface accordionPropsType {
    title: string
    children: ReactNode
}

const Accordion = (props: accordionPropsType) => {

    const [setActive, setActiveState] = useState("");
    const [setHeight, setHeightState] = useState("0px");
    const [setRotate, setRotateState] = useState("accordion__icon");

    const content = useRef(null);

    const toggleAccordion = () => {
        setActiveState(setActive === "" ? "active" : "");
        setHeightState(setActive === "active" ? "0px" : `${content.current.scrollHeight}px`);
        setRotateState(setActive === "active" ? "accordion__icon" : "accordion__icon rotate");
    }

    return(
        <Fragment>
            <div className="accordion__section">
                <button className={`accordion ${setActive}`} onClick={toggleAccordion}>
                    <p className="accordion__title">{props.title}</p>
                    <Chevron className={`${setRotate}`} width={10} color={"#777"} />
                </button>
                <div
                    ref={content}
                    style={{ maxHeight: `${setHeight}` }}
                    className="accordion__content"
                >
                    {props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
            <style jsx>
            {`
                /* Style the accordion section */
                .accordion__section {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    margin: 10px;
                }
                
                /* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */
                .accordion {
                    background-color: #eee;
                    color: #444;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    padding: 18px;
                    display: flex;
                    align-items: center;
                    border: none;
                    outline: none;
                    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
                }
                
                /* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
                .accordion:hover,
                .active {
                    background-color: #ccc;
                }
                
                /* Style the accordion content title */
                .accordion__title {
                    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
                    font-weight: 600;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    text-align: left;
                }
                
                /* Style the accordion content panel. Note: hidden by default */
                .accordion__content {
                    background-color: white;
                    overflow: auto;
                    transition: max-height 0.6s ease;
                    margin: 5px;
                }
                
                /* Style the accordion content text */
                .accordion__text {
                    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
                    font-weight: 400;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    padding: 18px;
                }
            `}
            </style>
        </Fragment>
    );
}

export default Accordion;
```

And this is the component that calls this child component:

```
import React, { useState, Fragment, useEffect, FormEvent } from "react"
import Select from "../components/Select"
import Accordion from "../components/Accordion"
import Table from "../components/Table"

interface findingsType {
    body: object
    header: Array<headersType>
}

interface headersType {
    className: string
    rows: Array<rowType>
}

interface rowType {
    className: string
    rowspan: number
    colspan: number
    text: string
}

const CloudFindingsList = (props) => {

    const [groupBy, setGroupBy] = useState<Array<string>>([]);
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState<findingsType>(null);

    const headerRows = [] as Array<rowType>

    const headers = [{
        className: "thead_custom" as string,
        rows: headerRows
    }] as Array<headersType>


    console.log('eee')

    const getGroupBy = (event) => {

        let distinctGroupsBy = []
        let allFindings = {}

        props.findings.map(finding => {
            let value = finding[event.target.value]
            distinctGroupsBy.includes(value) ? '' : distinctGroupsBy.push(value)
        })            

        distinctGroupsBy.map(order => {
            allFindings[order] = []
        })

        props.findings.map(finding => {
            let value = finding[event.target.value]
            distinctGroupsBy.map(order => {
                value == order ? allFindings[order].push(finding) : ''
            })
        });

        setGroupBy(distinctGroupsBy)

        console.log(groupBy)

        Object.keys(allFindings[distinctGroupsBy[0]][0]).map(value => {
            headerRows.push({
                className: "" as string,
                rowspan: 0 as number,
                colspan: 0 as number,
                text: value as string
            })    
        })

        setTableData({
            header: headers,
            body: allFindings
        } as findingsType)
    }

    const listFindings = 
        groupBy.map((group, index) => {
            return(
                <Accordion title={group} key={index}>
                    <Table jsonData={tableData.body[group]} header={tableData.header}/>
                </Accordion>
            )
        })

    return(
        <Fragment>
            <Select 
                id='1' 
                options={[{"val": "severity", "text": "severity"}, {"val": "account", "text": "account"}, {"val": "service", "text": "service"}]} 
                placeholder='Group by'
                handleChange={getGroupBy as () => {}}
            />
            {listFindings}
        </Fragment>
    );
}

export default CloudFindingsList
```

You don't have to understand all the code I just want that when I change the selected item in the selector the Accordion is closed again. Does anyone see the solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use a `useEffect` hook passing the props of the Accordion as change parameter. Every time that `prop` change you execute the code that changes the value.

```js
useEffect(() => {
 // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
}, [props])
```